# React SSR dynamically import components according to API response

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, react-router-v4

I am building SSR React app with razzle tool. Server is using express framework. I would like to load React components dynamically according to value included in API response.

I have folder structure like:

views
- default
-- Home.js
- theme1
-- Home.js

I am using SSR. On the server I have

```
const markup = renderToString( 
<Provider store={store}> 
   <StaticRouter context={context} location={req.url}> 
      <App theme={theme} /> 
   </StaticRouter> 
</Provider> 
);
```

Inside **App** component, I need to import component from corresponding subfolder or if its absent than import **default** component from the **default** subfolder. There can be many theme subfolders so I can't import all the components manually.

Should this by done on server by express or is there another way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this? I'm not quite sure if you are using server side rendering.

```
import DefaultComponent from './views/default.js';
import Theme1Component from './views/theme1.js';

this.state = {
     visibleDefault: true
}
```

You can then simply update the state base on the response.

Then in your render you can have this

```
render(){
    return(
       { visibleDefault ? <DefaultComponent/> : <Theme1Component/> }
    )
}
```